# Mouse Hover Over a Text, retrieve Details for that text from a Table

Tags: c#, asp.net

ALL, 
This is my first post on Stack Overflow.
I have been programming in C# for sometime. while doing so, i have come across a requirement where in one of the column of the Grid view, some text(Short text) is to be shown . now if a user hover mouse over this text, i want details which are related to this Short Text stored in some other table to be shown as a POP UP.

I have been looking around for long, but could not find a solution. please help.
I have no idea where to begin this with.

Comment: What kind of pop up. Do you want a tool tip like the one on the "share" link under your question, or do you want a full popup like what happens when you hover over the c# tag under your question

Comment: Yeah,similar to one when i hover over the C# tag. is it possible to add something in table format in this popup ? i don't want anything like which contains a share link or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery ajax will be a gool solution.
In the onhover event, get data from server using ajax, then build html and pop up(using jQuery Dialog).
Refer to jQuery ajax and dialog sample via below
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Thank All!! I was able to do it. i could find a Ajax Control from the AjaxControlTool kit : HoverMenuExtender. This Solved my problem. But is it advisable to use this control or go by code?